# Smart-like template engine for java?

Tags: java, templates, open-source

Is there any template engine (open source) that is like Smart? I want to make it easy for users to design their templates in HTML and then use it, which the smarty-template really is good for. JTPL is close to my example of what I'm looking for, but I want the "foreach" part in the template to be able to let users customize the result pages as well. The more lightweight the better!

Comment: Also, check Java Server Faces (or Pages), this is exactly what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[StringTemplate](http://www.stringtemplate.org/) is a popular lightweight Java template engine. Also, check out these instructions on [generating web pages with StringTemplate](http://www.cs.usfca.edu/~parrt/course/601/lectures/stringtemplate.html).

Answer (score 3):

[Velocity](http://velocity.apache.org/) is a nice, lightweight templating engine.

Answer (score 3):

[Freemarker](http://freemarker.org/) is good too. Quite similar to Velocity, add some nice features.

Answer (score 2):

Rythm is a Strong typed Java template engine using [Razor](http://razorengine.codeplex.com) like syntax with high performance (2 to 3 times faster than Velocity and FM). It provides a very lightweight way to do String interpolation:

```
String result = Rythm.render("hello @who!", "world");
```

This simplicity makes Rythm a good replacement for `String.format()` in many cases. Please be noted that `Rythm.render` is 2x faster than `String.format`

For comprehensive template you can use the same interface to pass in the file name:

```
Map<String, Object> args = new HashMap<String, Object>();
args.put("who", "world");
...
String result = Rythm.render("myTemplate.html", args);
```

Rythm has very rich feature set including java flow control (if-else, for loop, collection iteration), template inheritance, external and internal tags creation and invocation, caching, Java method extension, space compact, html escape etc. Most of the features are demonstrated at http://play-rythm-demo.appspot.com/. (And Yes, the demo is written with Play!Framework plus Rythm template engine and it is running on GAE!)

There is Play!Framework plugin created on Rythm engine, you can find documentation on how to use Rythm from there: http://www.playframework.org/modules/rythm

You can download Rythm from https://github.com/greenlaw110/rythm/downloads

There is also a Spring MVC plugin created based on Rythm Engine: https://github.com/lawrence0819/spring-web-rythm-template